# convert .mat file to a dataframe using scipy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I've this [matfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx7j4g6afbgboxq/KRS_FHD.mat?dl=0) which I would like to convert to a dataframe but from my code

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
matfile = 'matfile\path'
data = loadmat(matfile)
df_sc = pd.DataFrame(data['KRS_FHD'])
print(df_sc)
```

the dataframe I get have all elements as lists i.e., each element is a list.

I can get the desired dataframe if I use the pymatreader package, but I'm looking to achieve this using the default python packages (scipy).

```
from pymatreader import read_mat
matfile = 'matfile\path'
data = read_mat(matfile)
pd.DataFrame(data['KRS_FHD'])
```

Does anyone knows any alternative way to convert this with scipy?

Comment: There isn't an alternative loader.  But it may be possible to modify the array.  Without knowing what the two loaders produce, we can't help you.  MATLAB objects require significant adaptation to use in python.

Comment: Looking at the `pymatreader` code, I see that it does use `loadmat`.  But then it does some further manipulation of the result.  If the MATLAB is cells or struct, the `loadmat` result will be a complicated nesting of structured arrays and object dtype arrays.  Either stick with that reader, or figure out on your own, where the desired data is in `data['KRS_FHD']`

Comment: Thanks. I'll check how pymatreader is implemented and see if I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
data_set = loadmat(matfile, struct_as_record=True, squeeze_me=True, mat_dtype=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_set['KRS_FHD'])
df
```

scipy.io.loadmat have some optional arguments that can be used here.
[scipy.io.loadmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) doc